# Why can't I pipe to output.txt or grep -v?

Tags: bash

I need to be able to grep through the output of this command.  It works fine if I leave it off after 'done', but I can't search through the output and am unable to pipe it out or use grep.

Putting the `|` or `>>` right after `./binaryfile` doesn't seem to work either.

```
for i in {0..32767}; do 
    printf "AAAAAAAAAAAAA\x$(printf %x $i)" | ./binaryfile; 
    killall -s KILL binaryfile; 
done >> output.txt
```

I should get a greppable text file with all the results.  Instead, the file(or grep) is completely empty.

Comment: Stop using SIGKILL. It doesn't let the program flush its unwritten buffers, and when output is to a file or pipe, the standard C library operates in buffered mode by default, so content isn't written until there's a full buffer's worth. If you *must* shut a program down early, use SIGTERM.

Comment: Why do you need to use `killall`? The next statement doesn't execute until after the `./binaryfile` command finishes. You're not running it in the background.

Comment: Are you sure that `./binaryfile` is writing to standard output?

Comment: Do you see the output on the terminal instead of in the file?

Comment: If it's writing to `stderr`, add `2>&1` after `>> output.txt`.

Comment: @Barmar, ...if it were writing to stderr, the OP would be asking why they still see the output on their terminal, not why the output doesn't exist at all. I'm assuming that the program they run is self-daemonizing.

Comment: I have to kill the program early because it's a buffer overflow and it kills my computer if I don't.  Tried doing it with just `killall binaryfile` and I still get no output.txt.

Yes, if I run the command without `>> output.txt` I get about 6 lines of output per iteration.

Comment: But the `killall` doesn't run until the program exits by itself. There shouldn't be anything to kill. Does the program fork children that run in the background and then exit the parent process?

Comment: @Cerkoryn, ...Barmar is right, though, insofar as that *if your program is well-behaved*, the `killall` will have no effect at all, because by the time the pipeline finishes and the `killall` command runs, the program will have already exited. So your program is behaving badly, by letting its parent process exit while it leaves a subprocess (presumptively, the subprocess responsible for flushing output) still running. It'd be better to fix that properly, instead of mucking around with half-arsed workarounds.

Comment: If that's what the program is doing, your `killall` isn't giving it enough time to write anything. You need to put a `sleep` command before it, to allow it to run for a little while before killing it.

Comment: @Cerkoryn, ...that said, it's also possible that the program checks whether `isatty(1)` is true, and only writes the content you expect when that check comes back true. That's another place where your program is simply behaving a way it shouldn't, and it's that program's fault, and that program's code you should fix.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm just guessing, but I suspect this behavior of the program is intentional, as some kind of shellcode.

Comment: @Cerkoryn, ...*if* the problem is the TTY hack, a cheap awful workaround would be to replace `... | ./binaryfile` with `... | unbuffer ./binaryfile`, after installing `expect` (the program with which `unbuffer` is packaged). But even if that works, you shouldn't do it -- you should fix `binaryfile`'s bugs instead.

Comment: Anyhow, a [mcve] would include a stand-in for `binaryfile`, such that you'd accept an answer that fixed the problem for that stand-in. As it is, nobody but the OP can test answers' correctness, which makes it impossible for others to determine their correctness or value, and impossible for people with similar problems to conclusively determine whether an answer is likely to be helpful to them as well.

Comment: I've tried running it without `killall` and I get errors about a fork after several iterations and my computer starts acting funky, needing a restart to fix.  

It's not my program, it's one provided from a popular CTF.  I've also disassembled it which is what lead me to try the buffer overflow in the first place.  It seems to work without the output redirection, but I can't parse through that many lines for the flag with just my naked eye.

Comment: If you've disassembled it, you should be able to build a [mcve]. We expect people asking questions here to put in that effort.

Comment: @Cerkoryn : If you - just for the purpose of testing - replace `./binaryfile` by `cat`, do you then get something in output.txt?

Answer (score 0):

If the killall in the loop makes a difference, I think it means, that the binaryfile program didn't terminate properly, otherwise the killall would have no effect at all and would print an error message (no such process or something like this). 
So I think at first you should try to figure out, why the process doesn't terminate properly. Maybe it starts a child process while the parent process runs on exit. If you can't stop it from doing this easily, you could try to sync your processes in the bash script, so you don't get the problem with too many processes (killing them before they can do something interesting, doesn't really solve the problem).

For example, if you compile and run this script, you'll notice that you get a shell prompt, while the program still outputs messages:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(void) {
        pid_t parent_pid;
        pid_t my_pid;
        long i,j;

        parent_pid= getpid();

        fork();
        if(getpid() == parent_pid) {
                printf("I'm the parent process, Ill terminate\n");
                exit(1);
        } else {
                printf("I'm the child process, I'll live a bit longer\n");
                for(i=0;i < 100;i++) {
                        printf("Iteration %ld\n", i);
                        for(j=0;j < 500000000; j++);
                }
        }
}
```

So I think you need to synchronize your processes or make sure the program has terminated before you start it next time. It seems for the example above I could not use wait (I mean the shell command), but if there is no other possibiility you could put something in your shell script like (although I know it's a bit awkward):

```
while pgrep binaryfile > /dev/null ; do
    sleep 2s
done
```